# Are there mentions in Hinduism about instruments which allows one to know others thoughts and influence them? And is it sinful?

Tags: yantra

Although I'm a native Hindu from India, my knowledge of Hinduism is confined to Mahabharata, Ramayana and few mantras from Upanishads.

I want to know if there are references to yantras in Puranas, Ithihasas, Vedas, Upanishads, etc which allows one to know thoughts of others and also influence thoughts of others through those yantras. If yes, what were such yantras called and what protections were recommended against them?

What crime would the people or person who used such yantras to know the thoughts of others be guilty of?

What crime would the people or person who used such yantras to influence the thoughts of others be guilty of?

What punishment is recommended for people who use yantras to know and/or influence thoughts of others? What karma will they suffer?

I in think such technology has been in existence since 1960s. I can show links for such if required.

Answer (score 9):

Highly accomplished Yogis can read what's going on in other's minds. This they can achieve by a process called *Samyama*. Here Yantras are not required.

This is a Yogic Siddhi and thus not a sin. Even deities know our thoughts and are witnesses of all our actions.

Patanjali Yoga Sutras Vibhooti Pada chapter has the following sutra:

> 19. pratyayasya para-chitta-jnanam ||
>
> By making Samyama on the signs in another’s both knowledge of that
>   mind comes.

Swami Vivekananda expounds on this sutra and says the following:

> Suppose each man has particular signs on his body, which differentiate
>   him from others; **when the Yogi makes a Samyama on these signs peculiar
>   to a certain man he knows the nature of the mind of that person.**

To know what Samyama is you need to read chapter 3 of the mentioned text from the start.

Dharana, Dhyana and Samadhi when done at the same time that's called Samyama.

> trayam ekatra samyamah ||
>
> (These) three (when practised) in regard to one object is Samyama.

To do Dhyana properly is quite difficult, to achieve the state of Samadhi is of course exceedingly difficult. So, we can assume how difficult it would be to accomplish Samayam. That's why the results that are obtained through it are kind of spectacular.

Comment: Please look at this site: stopeg.com and searching on Google for synthetic telepathy. Going by my experience I feel such technologies have been in existence 1960s. Isn't having such technology evil, and the religion doesn't talk about it, seems to allow it.

Comment: Since it is a achieved by Yogic practice, which in itself, erases all sins, so to be able read others' minds is not sinful from the perspective of my answer .. but I will have to go through the sites u have mentioned to know what they actually do to know others' thoughts .. also as I have said, influencing others thought seems to be not right @NeedAnswers

Comment: Thanks, which spellings? from my own texts or those in the yellow quote?

Comment: @Rickross Also, samadhi is the end step.What is meant by three done at the same time?

Comment: @commonman accomplished yogis when we first close eyes Dharana happens,  then within few seconds Yogi enters stage of Dhyan and then Samadhi quickly. Within quick span Yogi enters Atma stage!

Comment: You need to see the definition of Samadhi in Raja Yoga and also of the remaining two .. when Dharana, Dhyana and Samadhi are done simultaneously on the same object, the result is called Samyam .. @commonman

Comment: @Rickross What is the position when thoughts are known through technologies? And when they are influenced through technologies?

Comment: Scriptures don't mention about any such technologies @NeedAnswers

Comment: @Rickross: Upvoted.  Many saints advice not go after siddhis, as after putting in hard work in dhyana, it is not worth to waste that fruits on petty issues like understanding others' thinking, telepathy, etc.