# Is it possible to convey the message through telepathy?

Tags: vedas

Is it possible to read minds with telepathy? Is it mentioned anywhere like Vedas?

Comment: Related or Possible duplicate of [Are there mentions in Hinduism about instruments which allows one to know others thoughts and influence them? And is it sinful?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34433/3500)